# How to save a data frame as CSV to a user selected location using tcltk

Tags: r, csv, save, dataframe

I have a data frame called, `Fail`.

I would like to save `Fail` as a CSV in a location that the user selects.  Below is some example code that I found, but I don't know how to incorporate `Fail` into it.

```
require(tcltk)
fileName <- tclvalue(tkgetSaveFile())
if (!nchar(fileName)) {
    tkmessageBox(message = "No file was selected!")
} else {
    tkmessageBox(message = paste("The file selected was", fileName))
}
```

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Take a look at the `write.csv` or the `write.table` functions. You just have to supply the file name the user selects to the `file` parameter, and the dataframe to the `x` parameter:

```
write.csv(x=df, file="myFileName")
```

Comment: I didn't see it mentioned, so I thought it would be useful to mention the
    `row.names = F`
parameter that will remove the rownames from taking up an output column

Answer (score 33):

You need not to use even the package "tcltk". You can simply do as shown below:

```
write.csv(x, file = "c:\\myname\\yourfile.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

Give your path inspite of "c:\myname\yourfile.csv".

Answer (score 8):

```
write.csv([enter name of dataframe here],file = file.choose(new = T))
```

After running above script this window will open :

[image]

Type the new file name with extension in the **File name** field and click **Open**, it'll ask you to create a new file to which you should select **Yes** and the file will be created and saved in the desired location.